# http2 request returning bad request

Tags: c, sockets, curl, request, http2

I have a C program of socket which has to use http2 protocol. It is returning Bad Request - HTTP Error 400. The request is badly formed.

Initially, I sent a request like the following through curl 7.64:

```
curl -v -http2 -i https://mywebsite.xyz
```

and i got the following output:

```
* Expire in 0 ms for 6 (transfer 0x55cc25ec95c0)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55cc25ec95c0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55cc25ec95c0)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55cc25ec95c0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55cc25ec95c0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55cc25ec95c0)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55cc25ec95c0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55cc25ec95c0)
* Expire in 0 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55cc25ec95c0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55cc25ec95c0)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55cc25ec95c0)
* Expire in 1 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55cc25ec95c0)
* Expire in 2 ms for 1 (transfer 0x55cc25ec95c0)
*   Trying 10.8.0.253...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x55cc25ec95c0)
* Connected to mysite.xyz (10.8.0.253) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; postalCode=XXXX; ST=XX; L=XXXXX; street=XXXXXXXXXXXX; O=XXXXXX; OU=PremiumSSL Wildcard; CN=*.XXXXXXX
*  start date: Nov 20 00:00:00 2018 GMT
*  expire date: Feb 21 23:59:59 2021 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "mysite.xyz" matched cert's "*.mysite.xyz"
*  issuer: C=GB; ST=Greater Manchester; L=Salford; O=COMODO CA Limited; CN=COMODO RSA Organization Validation Secure Server CA
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x55cc25ec95c0)
> GET / HTTP/2
> Host: mysite.xyz
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 100)!
< HTTP/2 200 
HTTP/2 200 
< content-type: text/html
content-type: text/html
< last-modified: Mon, 01 Jul 2019 17:57:17 GMT
last-modified: Mon, 01 Jul 2019 17:57:17 GMT
< accept-ranges: bytes
accept-ranges: bytes
< etag: "c7c5406c3630d51:0"
etag: "c7c5406c3630d51:0"
< server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
< date: Mon, 01 Jul 2019 19:45:53 GMT
date: Mon, 01 Jul 2019 19:45:53 GMT
< content-length: 51
content-length: 51

< 
<html>
<head></head>
</body>Hello</body>
* Connection #0 to host mysite.xyz left intact
</html>
```

From the above request-response log, I took the following:

```
GET / HTTP/2
Host: mysite.xyz
User-Agent: curl/7.64.0
Accept: */*
```

and created a request like the following:

```
char* inputString = "GET / HTTP/2\r\nHost: mysite.xyz\r\nUser-Agent: curl/7.64.0\r\nAccept: */*\r\n\r\n"
```

But, this time I am getting error like:

```
Connected with ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 encryption
Received: "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Date: Mon, 01 Jul 2019 20:28:48 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 311

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request is badly formed.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTTP/2 is not a "simple" text based protocol like HTTP/1. This means that you cannot just send a HTTP request as text to the TCP socket but must instead use the binary representation of the request as defined by the (fairly complex) HTTP/2 standard. What curl shows in the debug output is just a text interpretation of the request but not the actual representation on the wire. For more see [RFC 7540](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540). Note that you additionally to the binary encapsulation need to set the ALPN extension in TLS to `h2` in order to announce to the server that you will use HTTP/2.

In your specific case the request was send as text-based (no ALPN `h2` set and no HTTP/2 encapsulation) but with an unknown protocol specification for text-based, i.e. `HTTP/2` instead of `HTTP/1.1` or similar. The server therefore correctly treated the request as invalid.

Comment: This was exactly I was looking for. I switched to adding the openssl libraries in my C code and it worked for any request till HTTP1.1. Unfortunately it did not worked for HTTP/2 for which I used nghttp2 library.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich ok thanks, will delete and repost as a fresh question. thanks for the reply.