# http2 request returning - http error 400. the request verb is invalid

Tags: iis, request, http2

I am writing a C socket program to send a http2 request to my Microsoft IIS server. The following is my current request which i am sending:

```
char *msg ="HEADERS\r\n+END_STREAM\r\n+END_HEADERS\r\n:method=GET\r\n:scheme=https\r\n:path=/\r\nhost=newsite.xyz.com\r\naccept=*/*\r\n\r\n";
```

I am new to http2 protocol and its the first time I am crafting a request based on the [RFC7540](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540)

On the execution of my socket program running the above statement, it gives me the following error:

```
Connected with ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 encryption
Received: "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Date: Tue, 02 Jul 2019 16:25:32 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 326

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid Verb</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request verb is invalid.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
"
```

Other part of the C Socket program are correct and it has been tested against other https request.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http2 request returning bad request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56842062/http2-request-returning-bad-request)

Comment: The reason is the same as your previous question. You are trying to treat HTTP/2 as if it was text based like HTTP/1.1 but that will not work.

Comment: @BarryPollard So my question would be that is there any sample request available anywhere so that i can get an idea how exactly the request should look like ?

Comment: HTTP/2 is a complex protocol that will be difficult to implement from scratch. If using C I would suggest looking at nghttp2 to handle HTTP/2 for you. There are examples of client applications on the projects home page.